# Metaclass not altering attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

Why is the following metaclass not converting all attributes to upper case? Instead it seems to be doing nothing.

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):

        uppercase_attr = {}
        for name, val in dct.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                uppercase_attr[name.upper()] = val
            else:
                uppercase_attr[name] = val

        return super(UpperAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attr)


class MyKlass(object):
    __metaclass__ = UpperAttrMetaclass

    def __init__(self):
        print ("Instantiating the object in the __init__ of the class")

    def foo(self, param):
        pass

    some_attribute = 2

print("")
print ("--------------------------------------")
print ("This is the first line of the program")
print ("--------------------------------------")
m = MyKlass()
print(m)
print(m.__dict__)
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're using python 2 and not python 3? Also, you're checking the dict of an _instance_, not the dict of the _class_.

Comment: Yes this syntax wouldn’t work in python 3 and the meta class is definitely called. And eitherway. MyKlass.__dict__ or m.__dict__ has lower class atributes

Comment: You're still looking at the wrong thing. Try `print(MyKlass.__dict__)`.

Comment: ok you're right. So it's only the class that's affected but not the objects?

Comment: Yes, that's how metaclasses work. They make classes, not instances. If you want to make changes to the instance attributes, you can either override the `__setattr__` method or replace the object's `__dict__` with a custom dict-like class that converts its keys to upper case.

Comment: and that would have to happen in the metaclass?

Comment: I believe overriding the `__dict__` has to be done in the metaclass. Overriding `__setattr__` can be done in the class or the metaclass. Can you [edit] your question to clarify what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from the comments, if you want to set all instance attributes directly to upper case, you can simply implement `__setattr__` on the class itself. (and maybe `__getattr__` in order to normalize all attribute access)

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):

        uppercase_attr = {}
        for name, val in dct.items():
            if not name.startswith('__'):
                uppercase_attr[name.upper()] = val
            else:
                uppercase_attr[name] = val

        return super(UpperAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, uppercase_attr)

   def __setattr__(cls, attr, value):
      if not attr.startswith("__"):
          attr  = attr.upper()
      super(UpperAttrMetaclass, cls).__setattr__(attr, value)

class MyKlass(object):
    __metaclass__ = UpperAttrMetaclass

    def __init__(self):
        print ("Instantiating the object in the __init__ of the class")

    def foo(self, param):
        pass

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
         super(MyKlass, self).__setattr_(attr.upper(), value)

    some_attribute = 2
```

With the `__setattr__` on the metaclass as well, you ensure class attributes et after the class is created are also converted to uppercase. For ordinary instance attributes, only the `__setattr__` in the class is needed.